# HTML Canvas doesn't draw lines with a too big canvas on mobile

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Edit (4-4-2022):
I think I found the problem. It has something to do with how much memory the iPhone wants to give for the canvas. Here are some resources that I found:
https://pqina.nl/blog/total-canvas-memory-use-exceeds-the-maximum-limit/
https://pqina.nl/blog/canvas-area-exceeds-the-maximum-limit/

I am making a website where you can draw on an HTML canvas on your phone with p5js. But there is this one issue when I create the canvas with the function `createCanvas()` and set the width bigger than 932, it doesn't draw the lines. With a width of 932 or smaller, it works perfectly. It also draws the lines when in dev mode in chrome with iPhone 12 as selected device. Only when the canvas is bigger than 932 does it break on my phone. Everything seems to work in the code while the width is bigger than 932. With chrome on IOS, I checked the debugger via chrome://inspect, and the variables (such as the touches variable of the p5js library ) are passed through and the touch events work, the only thing that it doesn't do is draw the lines.

Some things you need to know about the website that I am building:

- You are able to draw with one finger and you can scroll through the canvas with two fingers. That is why I want the canvas to be big. So that the user can scroll through it.
- You scroll in the main element not directly in the canvas element.
- There is a UI element on top of the canvas where you can select colors.

I disabled most of the touch events with `preventDefault();` so that I can implement my own touch events; drawing with one finger and scrolling with two.

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");

let canvas;

// scrollX and scrollY are the amount to scroll throught the main element
let scrollY;
let scrollX;

// ptouch is the previous touch coordinates
let ptouchX;
let ptouchY;

let onCanvas = false;

// Check if canvas is touched. If it
document.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    if (event.target.isEqualNode(canvas.canvas)) {
        // Check if canvas is touched
        onCanvas = true;
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        onCanvas = false;
    }
}, { passive: false });

// Prevent all touchmove events
document.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
    if (onCanvas || event.scale !== 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, { passive: false });


document.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ptouchY = 0;
    ptouchX = 0;
});


function setup() {
    // canvas = createCanvas(932, 2000);
    canvas = createCanvas(2000, 2000);
    canvas.parent(main);
    strokeWeight(3);
    stroke(0);
}

function draw() {

    // Get the first touch coordinates and return;
    if (touches.length > 0 && (!ptouchX || !ptouchY)) {
        ptouchX = touches[0].x;
        ptouchY = touches[0].y;
        return;
    }

    // Drawing lines when there is one finger and there is a previous touch coordinates.
    if (touches.length === 1 && ptouchX && ptouchY && onCanvas) {
        line(touches[0].x, touches[0].y, ptouchX, ptouchY);
    }

    // Scroll throught the main element
    if (touches.length === 2) {
        scrollX = ptouchX - touches[0].x;
        scrollY = ptouchY - touches[0].y;

        main.scrollBy(scrollX, scrollY);
        return;
    }

    // While there are touches, the current touches become the previous touches.
    if (touches.length > 0) {
        ptouchX = touches[0].x;
        ptouchY = touches[0].y;
        return;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
  <title>Drawing app</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    main {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <main id="main"></main>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

I thought that it might be a styling err. That Safari or Chrome changes the size of the canvas or some other element but in the chrome debugger on ios, the canvas width returns 2000. The code works fine so the browsers don't disable some functionalities either.

I am trying to think why this behavior would occur but I can't think of anything.

And also I have a windows laptop.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any issue with an iPhone running 14.8.1 using either Safari or Google Chrome.

Comment: @PaulWheeler May I ask how you reproduced it and on which iPhone? I still have the same issue with my project.